# An answer that will make sense

Tags: visual

**Make sense of what you see below and give me the correct answer.**

[image]

Comment: Nice graphics ..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is simply

> **TOP VIEW**

<s>Literally</s> Visually

> [image: Image from top]

Comment: Fast, nice job!